# not exists return empty result set

Tags: mysql

Database contains 4 tables - fee, month, customer, invoice.

**Table - `month` (Fee Period)**

*(contains all months Jan-Dec, only two months is in here to shorten question)*

```
id  |   ttl |   year
====================
1   |   Jan |   1
2   |   Feb |   1
```

**Table - `fee` (Fee Name)**

```
id  |   ttl     |   year
========================
1   |   Annual  |   1
2   |   Monthly |   1
3   |   Extra   |   1
```

**Table - `customer` (Customer Name)**

```
id  |   ttl     |   year
========================
1   |   Rahul   |   1
```

**Table - `invoice` (Invoices list)**

```
id  |   cid |   fid |   mid
===========================
1   |   1   |   1   |   1
2   |   1   |   2   |   1
```

During 12 month, monthly and extra fee have to be payed in **each month**.

But annual fee is payed **at once**, in which month it is not fixed, it can be payed in Jan or Dec or any month between those month.

Now my requirement is show every fee with related month which invoice is not ready (fee name of each month that are not in invoice table), simply list of those months fee which are not paid. So I use `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL`

```
SELECT
    customer.id AS cid,
    month.id AS mid,
    fee.id AS fid,
    month.ttl AS mth,
    fee.ttl AS fee,
FROM
    fee
LEFT JOIN
    month ON month.year = fee.year
LEFT JOIN
    customer ON customer.year = fee.year
LEFT JOIN
    invoice ON invoice.mid = month.id AND invoice.fid = fee.id
WHERE
    customer.id=1 AND invoice.fid IS NULL
```

Result is -

```
cid |   mid |   fid |   mth |   fee 
=======================================
1   |   1   |   3   |   Jan |   Extra
1   |   2   |   1   |   Feb |   Annual  
1   |   2   |   2   |   Feb |   Monthly 
1   |   2   |   3   |   Feb |   Extra
```

but, what I want - As I stated above, Annual fee is paid only once, so if Annual is in invoice, exclude this, if not include, to get following result

```
cid |   mid |   fid |   mth |   fee 
=======================================
1   |   1   |   3   |   Jan |   Extra
1   |   2   |   2   |   Feb |   Monthly 
1   |   2   |   3   |   Feb |   Extra
```

because Annual fee is paid already in Jan.

So I've edit where condition

```
WHERE
    customer.id=1 
AND 
    invoice.fid IS NULL 
AND 
    NOT EXISTS (select invoice.fid from invoice where invoice.fid = 1 AND invoice.cid=customer.id)
```

but  MySQL returned an empty result set

Comment: Make sure the input you have included covers what is in your output examples, it's very confusing when you have output that doesn't exist in the input.

Comment: Can you post up a fiddle

Comment: @Strawberry, please wait I will show fiddle

Comment: just simply add `and fee.id != 1` in your where condition ? OR, `and fee.ttl != 'Annual'` ?

Comment: Also, you should do inner join between fee and month; since you want to consider all the months

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, adding `fee.id != 1` doesn't show annual fee any time. but I want to show `annual fee` if not payed, but if payed at once then not show. It mean if `annual fee` is in invoice, then stop to show, but if not then show.

Comment: @AnandHmt are the title fields named as `ttl` or `en_ttl` ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, sorry.. my mistake it have to be `ttl`, that's why I am getting error edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are missing a JOIN condition between `invoice` and `customer` table for the customer `id`.
- Due to joining between `month` and `fee` table, you are getting multiple rows for the case when `fee.ttl = 'Annual'`.
- One way is to break this into two different SELECT queries, and use `UNION ALL`. First select query considers `fee.ttl != 'Annual'`. Second select considers only those cases where `fee.ttl = 'Annual'`. In the second Select query, we don't join with the `month` table, thus avoiding multiple rows for 'Annual'.
- **Note that** I have matched 'Annual' against `ttl` field, instead of `fid`. It seems that you will have multiple `fid` values for 'Annual' due to different year(s). So checking `fid = 1` will only serve the purpose for `year = 1`.
- **Also note that** I have changed some of your Left joins to Inner join, because of your join table(s) ordering.

Try the following:

```
(SELECT
    customer.id AS cid,
    month.id AS mid,
    fee.id AS fid,
    month.ttl AS mth,
    fee.ttl AS fee 
FROM
    fee
INNER JOIN
    month ON month.year = fee.year
INNER JOIN
    customer ON customer.year = fee.year
LEFT JOIN
    invoice ON invoice.mid = month.id AND 
               invoice.fid = fee.id AND 
               invoice.cid = customer.id 
WHERE
    customer.id = 1 AND 
    fee.ttl != 'Annual' AND 
    invoice.fid IS NULL
)

UNION ALL 

(SELECT
    customer.id AS cid,
    '' AS mid,
    fee.id AS fid,
    '' AS mth,
    fee.ttl AS fee 
FROM
    fee 
INNER JOIN
    customer ON customer.year = fee.year
LEFT JOIN
    invoice ON invoice.fid = fee.id AND 
               invoice.cid = customer.id 
WHERE
    customer.id = 1 AND 
    fee.ttl = 'Annual' AND 
    invoice.fid IS NULL
)
```

Comment: I am amazed why it is down-voted.. seems it can be solution.. I'm testing it.

Comment: @AnandHmt there was an error in the code. In the second select, I was still using month table references in the Select. I have fixed it. Please use the updated query

Comment: @AnandHmt check the latest query. Also please update here if you are getting some syntax errors ?

Comment: Great sense of debugging !! Man, even I can't clarify my own problems easily, were still unclear, but your answers (adding previous) tends to simplify problems comfortably. Thanks dude !!!. correct typo error - `,` is before `FROM` and `AND` is missing after `'Annual'` in both query.

Comment: @AnandHmt fixed the typos. Thanks for spotting them.

Comment: please help to resolve problem, well it is not in question - but related to this. Here I am using **static** `customer.id` such as `customer.id` = `1`, for pure mysql usage and demo, but in real, **user input** is used instead of static number,  so I changed `customer.id = :cid`, ( `$result->bindParam(':cid', $_POST['cid']);`), but I get : `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number`, why this error ? Does it count two queries :cid as **two times** ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181397/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-anandhmt).